# Linux Embedded Device Screen Remote Access

Tags: linux, remote-access

I have a Variscite DART-6UL SoM running Linux version 4.9 and gcc 7.3.0 connected to a small LCD screen. The screen displays either a set of buttons, like a basic home menu screen, or some dials. The user navigates through all this with a rotary button or arrow keys and an "Enter" button.

**Software Requirements**

- Server needs to run on a Linux device
- Access the shared screen through a web page for compatibility with mobile devices
- Enable unattended access (a user doesn't have to accept the connection server side)
- Connection can be setup through the command line (no app or GUI)
- Free for commercial use

**Question:**
Anyone know a screen sharing software that meets the above requirements?

**My Research**

I have done some research on this but I haven't found anything that matches what I'm looking for. TeamViewer, AnyDesk, LogMeIn, SupRemo, NoMachine, RealVNC are all good candidates but aren't free for commercial use. AeroAdmin must be setup through the app with no command line options.

I have found a few posts on stack exchange SF and SU but these were either outdated or not very informative.

Comment: Have you seen https://guacamole.apache.org/ ??

Comment: @chicks I did not know about Apache Guacamole, this is exactly what I was looking for, thank you!